# Monitoring Apache Logs with Microsoft Operations Management Suite

Tags: apache, logging

Having an issue with MS OMS picking up Apache httpd log updates at a defined interval. It appears that updates are only picked up if the log file is opened within the OS on the server. Does Apache hold log entries in memory or something until the file is accessed? Is there a way I can alter this behavior if this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change behavior with Windows Server 2012 in registry to allow logs to be picked up:

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem

NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate=0